# Android UI Best Practices for Display Field turning into Input Field

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm programming an android app with a list displaying images and some additional information like title, place, etc...

I'm new to the android ecosystem and wondering what are the best practices to implement a list element which normally displays the mentioned information and turns into input fields on a press on the listelement.

Do I have to draw the display elements (e.g. `TextField`) and the edit element on top of each other and set visible for either display or input? How to handle this generally? Or do I replace the layout responsible for the list element altogether?

I know that for the simple case of a text there is a simple solution for making the `EditText` field look like an uneditable `TextField`. I'm, however, looking for a general answer covering broader cases than just a `TextField`.

Thanks!

Comment: As I can understand you want to be able to edit some info of the selected listview element or add an info, right?

Comment: Exactly: I want to be able to display and possibly edit the information.

Comment: Are you going to open / load another Activity / Fragment after selecting an item or you need only to edit the fields?

Comment: I want to make the fields editable without loading another activity/fragment.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the elements of the `listview` a view flipper having two views.
one you textview and other and edittext.

`<ViewFlipper
   ...
   <TextView 
      ... />
   <EditText
      ... />
/ViewFlipper>`

Then in the `onItemClickListener` of the list items you can call `flipper.showNext()`;

So, flipper works like, it shows only the first view defined in it and on the subsequent call of `showNext()` it displays the next view defined in it.

So if you have 2 elements in it, it will behave as the coin with two sides.

Comment: plus point to use it is, its easy in constructing layout xml and using in code.

Comment: Interesting solution! I'm going to try this out!

Answer (score 1):

So in your situation there are a few ways you can achieve this.

First way is to build a layout which contains `TextView` and `EditText` and in first initialization your edit text won't be visible. And in your `OnItemClick` you have to hide your textview and show editext with value of your current data and option to edit.

The second way which I think is more user friendly is that you can show an `AlertDialog` after `OnItemClick` with custom layout where you can change the values and update the listview after user press Yes or do nothing is he selects No.

It depends on you which way you will do that, but I think the second option is the better one.

Comment: And how do I place different elements (in this case EditText and TextView) on top of eachother? Will they not be placed next to eachother even if only one of them is visible?

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` and align the second view depending on first one.